# Plotting rank for various models under different criteria in R

Tags: r, plot, rank

I have data like this :

```
        RMSE  MAE MAPE   CDC
GARCH   1      2   2     3      
eGARCH  2      1   3     2 
csGARCH 3      3   4     1
apGARCH 4      4   1     4
```

GARCH, eGARCH,..,apGARCH are various models and they are ranked by four criteria RMSE, MAE, MAPE, and CDC. I want to plot this data in a single plot, in such a way that user could understand rank of various models by looking the plot. In reality I have 6 models and 5 criteria. So, it is very cumbersome for the reader to look at the table. So, I want some visualization techniques for plotting such types of data, so that it could be easily understood which model has highest rank under different criteria.

Thanks

Comment: You can check with `?matplot`

Comment: can you give more detail and example ?

Comment: For `heatmap` : `heatmap(dd,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA)` with `dd` your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `heatmap` :

```
heatmap(dd,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,margins=c(9,9))
```

[image]

If you are OK with the reordering of your data, you can just do :

```
heatmap(dd,margins=c(9,9))
```

[image]

Note that `margins=c(9,9)` was just used so the plots fit in my screen.
More importantly, `dd` should be a matrix.

```
dd<-structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 4L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("GARCH", "eGARCH", 
"csGARCH", "apGARCH"), c("RMSE", "MAE", "MAPE", "CDC")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you doesn't have a huge dataset how about creating one barplot for each model were each bar is the value of a criteria

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df$model <- row.names(df)
df <- gather(df,criteria,value,-model)


ggplot(df,aes(x=criteria,y=value,fill=criteria)) + facet_wrap(~model) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

This will create the folowing plot[image]

Comment: it is a good approach but less appealing. But thanks for efforts.